# Google Cloud Messaging - Error [401 Unauthorized] on server only

Tags: http, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

My website (in php) should send Push notifications to an Android app. It used to work fine for some time, and suddenly stopped.

When I checked the return error code, it was 401 (Unauthorized)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using 0.0.0.0/0 as the allowed IPs. **Seems it is no longer allowed after a grace period**. So I set my DSL spool IP address and my server IP address. I have a dedicated IP to my cloud server (On RackSpace).

Then it worked in my localhost, but not on my cloud server. I also confirmed that my server outgoing IP is same as my server dedicated IP.

**I had to set my Servers IPv6 address to Allowed IPs. Then it worked again - perfectly**
[On Google Developers Console - API Credentials settings]

I'm documenting this for it would be helpful to someone else too.

Answer (score 0):

Change the allowed  IPs  in your google console api project..